# How to access image Data from a RGB image (3channel image) in opencv

Tags: c++, c, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to take the imageData of image in this where w= width of image and h = height of image

```
for (int i = x; i < x+h; i++) //height of frame pixels
{
    for (int j = y; j < y+w; j++)//width of frame pixels
    {
        int pos = i * w * Channels + j; //channels is 3 as rgb 
        // if any data exists
        if (data->imageData[pos]>0) //Taking data (here is the problem how to take)
        {
            xPos += j;
            yPos += i;
            nPix++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This post has source code that shows what you are trying to accomplish: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293471/accessing-negative-pixel-values-opencv/3295141#3295141

Answer (score 4):

jeff7 gives you a link to a very old version of OpenCV. OpenCV 2.0 has a new C++ wrapper that is much better than the C++ wrapper mentioned in the link.  I recommend that you read the [C++ reference of OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/index.html) for information on how to access individual pixels.

Another thing to note is: you should have the outer loop being the loop in y-direction (vertical) and the inner loop be the loop in x-direction. OpenCV is in C/C++ and it stores the values in row major.

Answer (score 1):

See good explanation [here](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html#SECTION00053000000000000000) on multiple methods for accessing pixels in an IplImage in OpenCV.

From the code you've posted your problem lies in your position variable, you'd want something like `int pos = i*w*Channels + j*Channels`, then you can access the RGB pixels at

`unsigned char r = data->imageData[pos];`

`unsigned char g = data->imageData[pos+1];`

`unsigned char b = data->imageData[pos+2];`

(assuming RGB, but on some platforms I think it can be stored BGR).

Answer (score 1):

```
uchar* colorImgPtr;
for(int i=0; i<colorImg->width; i++){

    for(int j=0; j<colorImg->height; j++){

        colorImgPtr = (uchar *)(colorImg->imageData) + (j*colorImg->widthStep + i-colorImg->nChannels)

        for(int channel = 0; channel < colorImg->nChannels; channel++){

            //colorImgPtr[channel] here you have each value for each pixel for each channel
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few methods to do this (the link provided by jeff7 is very useful).

My preferred method to access image data is the `cvPtr2D` method.  You'll want something like:

```
for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        uchar* ptr = cvPtr2D(img, y, x, NULL);
        // blue channel can now be accessed with ptr[0]
        // green channel can now be accessed with ptr[1]
        // red channel can now be accessed with ptr[2]
    }
}
```

(img is an `IplImage*` in the above code)

Not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing this etc. but I find it the easiest and simplest way of doing it.

You can find documentation for this method [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_operations_on_arrays.html).